# Firebase templates with email validation

Tags: email, react-native, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

I am using firebase in a react native app.

For this app, I'm using email/password authentication and email verification, and it all works fine.

When a user validates his account by clicking on the link, it redirects to a page that reports that the email has been verified.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C3Sg.jpg)

I need to change the message. In the firebase console, I am not allowed to do this. I have not found anything that can help me with making changes to the linked page.

How can I change the verification message?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement your own custom email action landing page. This includes updating the action callback URL in the Firebase Console and building your own page to parse the action code from the URL and apply it before showing your custom message. Check the Firebase documentation for this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: Oh I see, that was that simple... 
I'll do this tomorrow and come back to you if I have a problem.

Thanks for the answer